# Is there a way to support rate limit in the client code generated by OpenAPI Generator?

Tags: openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I'm using `openapi-generator-cli`. A general solution will be preferred i.e. language agnostic but I'm using golang if the solution has to be language-specific.